# I can't enable Swap space on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, swap

So I'm following a tutorial to install OTRS which is Open source Ticket Request System. So in order to install, it requires: 4GB of Swap space. Here's the command I used:

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-41 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       50G   14G   37G  27% /
devtmpfs        478M     0  478M   0% /dev
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           496M   13M  484M   3% /run
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
[root@ip-10-0-7-41 ~]# fallocate -l 4G /myswap
[root@ip-10-0-7-41 ~]# ls -lh /myswap
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.0G Jul  8 08:44 /myswap
[root@ip-10-0-7-41 ~]# chmod 600 /myswap
[root@ip-10-0-7-41 ~]# mkswap /myswap
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 4194300 KiB
no label, UUID=3656082a-148d-4604-96fb-5b4604fa5b2e
[root@ip-10-0-7-41 ~]# swapon /myswap
swapon: /myswap: swapon failed: Invalid argument
```

You can see : Invalid argument error here. I tried many time in vain to enable it.Someone please tell me how to fix this error.
(I'm running this CentOS 7 on AWS Instance EC2)

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-41 ~]# df -T | awk '{print $1,$2,$NF}' | grep "^/dev"
/dev/xvda1 xfs /
```

Comment: What filesystem is this happening on? btrfs by any chance?

Comment: @schaiba Hello, i edited my question. I think filesystem is xfs.

Comment: On XFS indeed it's better to use `dd`. Please bear in mind that not all filesystems support swap or at least not in the same way.

Comment: @schaiba I didn't know very well about type of filesystem. Thanks so much.

Comment: The *invalid argument* is misleading. If you check the system logs, you'll probably see a corresponding message, `kernel: swapon: swapfile has holes`, which tells you what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The problem with `fallocate(1)` is that it uses filesystem `ioctls` to make the allocation fast and effective, the disadvantage is that it does not physically allocate the space but `swapon(2)` syscall requires a real space.
Reference : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1129205

I'd faced this issue earlier with my box too. So instead of using `fallocate`, I used `dd` as the link suggests

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/myswap count=4096 bs=1MiB
```

and moving ahead with `chmod`, `mkswap` & `swapon` commands. Bingo ! It worked.

Comment: Odd, an fallocate'd swap file worked fine for me on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS but it fails with "swapon failed: Invalid argument" on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo). The dd command provided above indeed works on RedHat. There must be something different between the two OSes that allows fallocate to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Solution works on CentOS 7.5

Comment: `dd` appears to be doing a lot more work `time dd if=/dev/zero of=/myswap count=4096 bs=1MiB` takes 14.003 seconds where `time fallocate -l 4G /swap3` takes 0.018 seconds, but they produce the same size file.  I am guessing that `fallocate` does not copy in zeros the way `dd` does and `swapon` needs those zeros.

Comment: `swapon: /swapfile: read swap header failed: Invalid argument` got this error after trying to `swapon /swapfile` on centos7 puppetenterprise server

Comment: @BrianThomas This sounds like you forgot to run mkswap on the file after you created it with dd.

Comment: thanks, I remember either mkswp was silently failing, or looked to run correct.  I cant recall now, i'll update if i find/remember what it was. I was following a doc though, so i did run that command.

Comment: @DanielWisehart `swapon` doesn't need the zeros. `swapon` needs the physical space to actually be there already, and not just reserved for future use. You could even fill your swap file with `/dev/random` and it would still work (but slow to create the swap file).

Comment: Neither of these methods worked for me on the latest Arch Linux on 27 August 2019.

Answer (score 23):

Follow these steps, it works on DigitalOcean's droplets. I tested. Change the amount 4096 according to your need

```
yum install nano -y

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4096 bs=1MiB
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile

sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

add this line:

```
/swapfile   swap    swap    sw  0   0
```

run this command

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10

sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

add this line

```
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50
```

To verify swap's size

```
swapon --summary
free -h
```

Comment: My `dd` command would be `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4 bs=1GiB` because I can't be bothered with calculating mebibytes in gibibytes if `dd` can do that for me. Did you know that in the days of yore people expressed it in kibibytes and hand-calculated that to gibibytes? Incredible!

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse you version of the dd command actually requires 1GiB of memory and the command will fail if you don't have that much free memory.

Comment: @Fabiano yes and? Your point is... ?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse my point is that if you just don't wanna bother with calculating MiBs and GiBs, `bs=` is not the proper way to do that, as it has unintended consequences, like hurt efficiency and likely not work on most low cost hostings. If you are just lazy, use `count_bytes` and let `dd` do for you both the math and choosing of an efficient block size: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4GiB iflag=count_bytes` =)

Comment: `iflag=count_bytes` is an excellent improvement to your comment. And I'm not lazy, I care about readability. In 6 months time when I read my script again (or when the next maintainer comes along), the reader must understand what is going on. It's not just computers who read code, humans read code too!

Comment: *"it works on DigitalOcean's droplets"* -> Not anymore; you have to set the NOCOW attribute **before you allocate space for the file**.  Ie., `touch swapfile`, then `chattr +C swapfile`, then `dd ....` (the attribute will remain set).

Answer (score 4):

In my case there was an error in the kernel log:

```
BTRFS warning (device sdd1): swapfile must not be copy-on-write
```

Disabling CoW (`chattr +c /swapfile`) before allocating space fixed the problem.